# static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

In Qt I am getting the following error when I try to compile...

C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\mingw49_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:725: error: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)

I am not entirely sure which signal and slot it is referring to as it is not giving me any more details but I suspect it is something to do with the following...
^
mainwindow.h

```
public slots:

void printCSV(QString getSerial, QString getCust, Loginput l);
```

printdialog.h

```
signals:

void printCSV(QString getSerial, QString getCust, Loginput l);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
connect(ui->buttonPrint, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=](){

checkCalibration(d, l); //run check calibration here to avoid missed inputs

printDialog = new PrintDialog(this);
printDialog->show();

connect(printDialog, &PrintDialog::printCSV, this, &MainWindow::printCSV);

});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: if you look at the full compiler output it likely contains more details

Comment: Your lambda function is not a part of `this` "receiver".

Comment: It seems to be referring to this `connect(printDialog, &PrintDialog::printCSV, this, &MainWindow::printCSV);`

Comment: @vahancho please can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @JoeSowerby, in this statement `connect(ui->buttonPrint, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=](){...` remove `this` parameter. Otherwise Qt treats it as you refer to your class' member function as a slot. The correct syntax is: `QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)`.

Comment: @vahancho That's not quite true.  When passing a functor/lambda you can also pass a [`QObject *`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5) that is used to determine the thread on which the lambda should be executed in the case of automatic or queued connections.  Although it's almost certainly redundant in this case.